# Batch file on hebrew folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to run a file on some folders whose names may contain hebrew characters and numbers.

I have a .bat file that copies files from and to the folders: 
if the folders have English letters or digits it runs great.

After I added the `chcp 1255` to my script now it also works on hebrew folders, but it doesnt work if it also have digits in it (see screenshots).
there are files that i need to copy to the folders so in this example i gave `myfile1.txt` that i want to copy to all folders
just for reference i have this folder `תקיה 1321321535`
and the script is

```
for /d %%a in (C:\Test\*) do copy /y C:\myfile1.txt %%a\
```

so it copy to all folders except the Hebrew folder.
Anyone can solve this?

[[image]]
[[image]]

now it doesnt show `????` when using `dir /b` cause i added Hebrew fonts but still doesnt copy the file
[image]

Comment: If you ask people why a script is not working as expected, you should (1) include the script in the question, (2) explain what is the expected outcome and (3) what are you getting instead. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanx for the reply , i tried to explain and wrote some code couldnt find where to upload my file

Comment: You don't have to upload a file, you can copy the minimal, complete and verifiable example in your post and apply the right format

Comment: As a first observation, the directory name `תקיה 321321535` contains a space. You probably want `copy C:\myfile1.txt "%a"` (note the doublequotes). As a second observation, it is a bad sign if the directory name appears to contain question marks -- it means that the characters cannot be represented in the current code page. First of all, check that you can do a `dir /b` and no question marks appear.

Comment: Hey you are right thats because if the space , and the ???? were because i didnt have the hebrew font not its working, can you explain why the double " ignored the space?

Comment: @JJJ: `cmd.exe` expects double quotes around arguments which include spaces (or other separators).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing double quotes (destination folder contains a space). Read [Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html):

```
d:\bat> pushd "D:\test\Unicode\תקיה"

D:\test\Unicode\תקיה> for /D %a in (*) do @echo %a
12323
תקיה 1321321535

D:\test\Unicode\תקיה> for /D %a in (*) do copy /y 01.txt %a\

D:\test\Unicode\תקיה> copy /y 01.txt 12323\
        1 file(s) copied.

D:\test\Unicode\תקיה> copy /y 01.txt תקיה 1321321535\
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

D:\test\Unicode\תקיה> for /D %a in (*) do copy /y 01.txt "%a\"

D:\test\Unicode\תקיה> copy /y 01.txt "12323\"
        1 file(s) copied.

D:\test\Unicode\תקיה> copy /y 01.txt "תקיה 1321321535\"
        1 file(s) copied.

D:\test\Unicode\תקיה>
```

Of course, in a batch script, double `%` percent sign as follows:

```
for /D %%a in (*) do copy /y 01.txt "%%a\"
```